# How to do this USB transfer?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, pc

[image]

I have a scenario that,

When receiving data through UART (STM) ,same time the data is    displayed in the notepad(opened in PC) through USB.

How can I implement this?

I am using stm32 micro controller

Figure(as given)

For example,

The data received by STM is employee id,at the same time data   should  displayed in PC.

**Note:**

I  too have **LPC1768**

Comment: Please clearify your specific problem

Comment: You could use third party apps or use command prompt or powershell. Is it an absolute requirement to use notepad?

Comment: @PrateekDhanuka notepad is not a requirement ..

Comment: You could use other text editors such as notepad++ or the command prompt itself to achieve this.

Comment: @PrateekDhanuka sir please give me the step to implement

Comment: If you are using an STM32 chip with an integrated USB controller, you can program it as a USB HID device, i.e. the PC would think it's a keyboard. That way you can insert the received data into any application that has the keyboard focus. Please provide more details about your chip and development environement.

Comment: @Codo yes..sir that's correct.the same way that i am thinking.but how could implement this? the micro controller is STM32 Arm Cortex. what format that i want to be transfer data to pc?

Comment: Please be more specific. There are so many different STM32 chips and boards out there. And do you have a preference for a certain development environment?

Comment: @Codo i dont have any preference..but  currently  i am using STM32F030C8T6TR

Comment: Unfortunately, the STM32F030C8T6TR doesn't have a USB controller. Is there any chance you can use a different chip? The STM32F070CB is probably the closest one with USB.

Comment: @Codo yes sir..i have LPC1768

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95852/discussion-between-shavan-we-and-codo).

Comment: There a plenty of examples available for the LPC1768. Just search for "LPC1768 HID example". Results will include [Mbed USBHID example](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.13/apis/usbhid.html#usbhid-example), [Keyboard Device example](https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-330796) etc.

Comment: @Codo yes..i got examples but how to modify according to my requirement

Comment: @Codo  which type of Descriptor that i want to declare?please give me in detail..

Comment: I have never used a LPC1768 so I can't really tell you the details. You'll have to dig into the topic yourself. But there is one more option I would like to mention: The FTDI FT260 provides UART to USB HID natively. There are boards available for about USD 10 (e.g. CJMCU-260). You can configure the board with a FTDI tool via USB and then you're all set.

Answer (score 3):

If you want data to Notepad, then the STM32 must be a keyboard HID to the PC, and it must convert serial data to keyboard presses. STM32 must have USB. But this may not be what you want.

If however the point is to watch serial data on screen and log it to a file, you would use a terminal program like putty to open a serial port. No microcontroller involved, just get a suitable serial cable or USB to serial adapter and it is done.

Comment: "If you want data to Notepad, then the STM32 must be a keyboard HID to the PC, and it must convert serial data to keyboard presses. STM32 must have USB. But this may not be what you want." ---->   Thats i wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can use Notepad++ to view data in a text file.

From within Notepad++: Settings > Preferences > MISC.

From there, you can check "Update silently" and "Scroll to the last line after update" in the group "File Status Auto-Detection"

Or you can use the command prompt as well, simply use `Tail -n 0 -f pathtotextfile`

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, build a UART to USB converter. You can build that on a breadboard. You can used FTDI IC. SOme microcontrollers are programmed through FTDI chips which converts RX/TX signals to USB's D+/D- signals.

As for a software to view received data from UART, you can use Terra Term.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the STM32 is a requirement or just happens to be the hardware you saw and began trying with.
However, there is much easier hardware (than stm32) to use to do this.

If you get an arduino Leonardo you can do this with a few lines of code.
You can pick up [three Leonardos for $20USD](https://amzn.to/2YDMNzT).

The Leonardo is small and will be seen as an HID device as soon as you connect it to your computer.  It uses the ATMega 32u4 which implements HID USB so you don't have to do all that work.

Once you get the Leonardo the code is as simple as this example shows:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/KeyboardSerial

```
#include "Keyboard.h"

void setup() {
  // open the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize control over the keyboard:
  Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // check for incoming serial data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read incoming serial data:
    char inChar = Serial.read();

    // Type the next ASCII value from what you received: 
    // this sends the data to your computer as if a user typed it on a keyboard.
    Keyboard.write(inChar + 1);
  }
}
```